# Replacement capacitor for fan lights

Tags: electrical, lighting, fans, capacitor

The lights on my fan stopped working, and changing the switch didn't help. When I try to turn it on, there's a little clicking sound that I believe is coming from the capacitor, and they flash on briefly before turning off. There's nothing on the capacitor that I can understand to find a replacement. The picture shows the only text on it.

What is this device and is it the likely culprit?

[image]

Comment: Not a capacitor but a current limiter , the government mandated limits on ceiling fans many years back. They can be found on line for a few dollars. Amazon PW-190 $3.79

Comment: I removed the "where to find it" portion of the question to focus on the "What is this and what's causing the problem" portion. "Where to find it" is shopping advice and that's off topic. Once you know what the thing is, you'll be able to go find it on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a capacitor but a current limiter.

the government mandated limits on ceiling fans lights many years back.

They can be found on line for a few dollars. Amazon PW-190 $3.79

I checked and it was 2005 when the limiters were mandated the max wattage was 190

Comment: Great, thanks! Just ordered one.

Comment: Old dog is still learning... +1

Comment: @glen Yates , we try to obey the law and provide advice that conforms with code. Your advice could end up causing damage to a electrical system if someone did not understand how to bypass or wirenut the correct wires , the wrong ones creates a direct short. , having been chastised in the past , please don’t  make such comments unless you want to make them an answer.